# -acodec option not working in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, server-configuration, video-conversion

Before I was using this:

```
ffmpeg -i file1.avi -acodec vorbis file2.ogg
```

And everything go okay... And now, on this new server, I try this command, and I get return Successful conversion, but there is no file...

It works only when I write this way:

```
ffmpeg -i file1.avi file2.ogg
```

But then audio codec is flac, and that can't be played in video in html5...

I tried with different codecs, like 10 different from list, and only 3 of 10 are creating files, but files with 0 bytes size...

About:

```
ffmpeg 0.7-rc1
libavutil    50. 40. 1 / 50. 40. 1
libavcodec   52.120. 0 / 52.120. 0
libavformat  52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
libavdevice  52.  4. 0 / 52.  4. 0
libavfilter   1. 77. 0 /  1. 77. 0
libswscale    0. 13. 0 /  0. 13. 0
```

All those codecs are enabled...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what version of ffmpeg you are using.  The latest git version says this:

> encoder 'vorbis' is experimental and
>   might produce bad results. Add
>   '-strict experimental' if you want to
>   use it. Or use the non experimental
>   encoder 'libvorbis'.

When I try:

```
ffmpeg -i file1.avi -acodec libvorbis file2.ogg
```

It works fine.

Comment: Yep, "-strict experimental" help... :)

Comment: @SharkTheDark I was able to convert by `ffmpeg -i video.avi -strict -2 video.mp4`